# Git aliasing truncates command definition

Tags: windows, git, cmd, alias, git-untracked

I have been trying to alias the following command for removing tracked files from the repository:

```
> git config --system alias.untrack 'rm --cached'
```

However when I check the configuration, the alias definition is truncated and throws when used:

```
> git config --list
alias.untrack='rm
> git untrack
fatal: bad alias.untrack string: unclosed quote
```

**How to avoid the above behaviour?**

Comment: Have you checked to make sure you don't have a global or local override of the alias with a bad value? Try `git config --list --global` and `git config --list --local` and see if anything sticks out. You can also check the system config file itself in a regular old text editor

Comment: @Phil when I `--list` the `config` I do not see another untrack alias or command. Let me see with your commands.

Comment: Not reproduced - `git config --global --list` shows this among other aliases: `alias.untrack=rm --cached` The same for --system wide configuration.

Comment: @DaneelOlivaw Yes but `--list` on its own will only show the final merged result

Comment: @Phil I have checked the `global` and `local` lists. The global config is not set up, and there is no conflicting alias or command with name `untrack` in the local one.

Comment: @DaneelOlivaw ok, so check the system config file. What OS are you using?

Comment: @Phil Windows 10.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess you ran the command in Windows CMD. If so, use double quotes instead of single quotes.

```
git config --system alias.untrack "rm --cached"
```

On Windows, `git bash` is recommended over `CMD` or `PowerShell`. With the latter 2, you have to deal with some annoying special characters.

Comment: This seems to have solved it, cheers!